# My script trying to create a server with mongoDB and nodejs giving error - db.collection is not a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am following up a tutorial to create a simple chat application using mongoDB and nodejs.The comments in the videos looking good,it seems that only I am facing this issue.Please help me with the code below.

```
//create a variable mongo and require the mongodb module here
const mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClient;

//create a variable called client,require socket and listen to particular port
const client=require('socket.io').listen(4000).sockets;

//connect to mongodb
mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat',function(err,db){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('MongoDB connected...');

    //start to work with socket.io

    //1.connect to socket.io
    client.on('connection',function(socket){
        let chat=db.collection('chats');

        //create function to send status to the client

        sendStatus =function(s){
            socket.emit('status',s);
        }
          //get chats from the mongo collections
          chat.find().limit(100).sort({__id:1}).toArray(function(err,res){
            //check for errors
            if(err) throw err;
            //else emit
            socket.emit('output',res);

          });
          //handle input events
          socket.on('input',function(data){
            let name=data.name;
            let message=data.message;

            //check for name and message 
            if(name==' '||message==' '){
                //send error status
                sendStatus('please enter name and message');
            }else
            {
                //insert message
                chat.insert({name: name,message: message},function(){
                    client.emit('output',[data]);

                    //send status objects
                    sendStatus({
                    message:'Message sent',
                    clear:true

                });

                });
            }
          });
          //handle clear
          socket.on('clear',function(data){
            //remove all chats from the collections
            chat.remove({},function(){
                //emit cleared
                socket.emit('cleared');
            })
          })



    })
})
```

It is giving an error db.collection is not a function.
I am a beginner in socket.io. So I couldn't find exactly why the error occurs.
Note:I am running mongoDB on a 32 bit windows machine(I even struggled installing it,but done with the help of stack overflow).
I have cross checked with the tutorial code for twice and even thrice.But I couldn't fix it.Please help me with this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using version 3.0 of the `mongodb` node driver. It's a new version and so a lot of tutorials are now slightly out of date. You can use `npm list mongodb` to check the version of your driver.

In older versions, this was the code:

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat', function(err, db){
  chat = db.collection('chats')
}
```

In 3.0, `MongoClient.connect()` passes a client object to its callback. So now it's:

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat', function(err, client){
  chat = client.db.collection('chats')
}
```

See the changelog of 3.0 [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md).

Of course, since you name your socket.io client `client`, you'll need to use a different name for one of those variables so they don't clash.

Comment: Thank you so much.I tried changing it to older version in package.json file and reinstalled.It worked for me.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped.